# Unable to delete Gmail profile in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, user-profiles

I used to have 2 Gmail profiles set up in Outlook 2010.  I initially had it set up using IMAP, but I deleted it (or so I thought), and re-set it up the old-fashioned way without IMAP.  Then finally, I deleted the 2nd Gmail profile altogether. So now I only have ONE Gmail profile set up in Outlook 2010 and it works fine.  The problem is that the original Gmail IMAP folder for the 2nd Gmail account is still in my list of folders when I use Outlook.  I've already disabled IMAP via my Google Gmail account.  But I am unable to delete the folder from Outlook 2010.  I have checked in the account settings and it is NOT in my list of email profiles or the data files.  Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

My shot in the dark guess is that Outlook is probably looking at the old data file that was left behind from the old gmail account (.PST file extension).

Can you verify there is a PST file in this location correlating to your old account?  Depending on the OS it may be located in a different location.

For Windows 7 it is

```
C:\Users\%username%\Documents\Outlook Files
```

For Windows XP it is

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\My Documents\Outlook Files
```

More information about Outlook PST files can be found [here](http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/aboutpst.htm).

Comment: thank you!! that was EXACTLY the problem. all fixed now!

Comment: Would you mind marking my post as the correct answer?  It may be helpful for other users with the same issue.